# How to retrieve local player highscore from Game Center

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center

Struggling to download and show the local players high score that's displayed on Game Center - the current code is showing 0 although score is 215

```
 GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
    leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,1);

    int64_t personalBest= (int64_t)(leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore.value * 1000000);

    CCLabelTTF *HighScoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",personalBest] fontName:@"MyScriptFont" fontSize:50.0];
    HighScoreLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    HighScoreLabel.position = ccp(0.65f, 0.7f);
    [self addChild:HighScoreLabel];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW32) you need to call the loadScoresWithCompletionHandler to retrieve the scores. So after making the range call the following.

```
[leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                // Handle the error.
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
                // Process the score information.
            }
            }];
```

Comment: Key bit i was missing.. was to state which leaderboard id doh!! leaderboardRequest.category= @"XXXXXXXX";